# Stop finder from opening search by default

Tags: finder, shortcut

I open finder with `option + cmd + space`.

Which on my second MBP opens a **Finder Search** window. (I then have to press cmd + n for new finder)

On my primary machine I have somehow set it to open a new Finder window by default.

**How can I get `option + cmd + space` to open a new finder window, NOT search?**

Tried:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Turn this off and then add a new shortcut in app shortcuts, with text exactly New Finder Window with keys you want.

Comment: Sounds right but I can't get it to open up a new finder window. Updating question.

Comment: The closest I could get was to set Show in Finder in text services to the shortcut and  select some text before hitting the shortcut. It changes focus to Finder.

Comment: Hey @ankiiiii today this change mysteriously began working. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @BenRacicot. that's good+ weird. Did you reboot in the mean time?

Comment: Nope! Yesterday after I applied it `opt+cmd+space` made the error sound (bmp!) Today I sat down and woke the MBP and `opt+cmd+space` opens a Finder window.

Comment: https://shouldiblamecaching.com